# php mysql dropdown value select

Tags: php, mysql

Currently the following code displays the filters for the individual publishers ie if I select DC I will only see the DC titles.

The issue is that from the current code I cannot get it to display all publishers from the dropdown menu.

```
<div id="main">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div id="search_query" >
     <select name="make" size="0">
      <option value="all">All Publishers</option>
      <option value="DC">DC</option>
      <option value="Marvel">Marvel</option>
      <option value="Image">Image</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

  </div>
</form>
<div id="main_container">
 <?php
 $db_con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','root');
 if (!$db_con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db('work', $db_con);
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $make = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);
   $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE publisher= '$make' ");

   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   echo "<table width= 970 border=1>
   <tr>
     <th width='120' scope='col'>Title</th>
     <th width='170' scope='col'>Publisher</th>
     <th width='185' scope='col'>Price</th>
     <th width='126' scope='col'>Desc</th>
   </tr>";
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $row['publisher'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>". $row['price'] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $row['desc'] ."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
 }
 else
 {
  $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products");
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  echo "<table width= 970 border=1>
  <tr>
   <th width='120' scope='col'>Title</th>
   <th width='170' scope='col'>Publisher</th>
   <th width='185' scope='col'>Price</th>
   <th width='126' scope='col'>Desc</th>
 </tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['title']. "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['publisher'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['price'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['desc'] ."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} 

mysql_close($db_con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is depreacated, try using `mysqli_* OR PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, it's searching for  publisher = $make where $make = "all". 
Your database table probably doesn't have any record with publisher = "make".

I'd suggest you to add an if else condition here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   $make = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);

   if ($make != "all") {
       $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE publisher= '$make' ");
   } else {
      $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products");
   }

   /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: thank you. All values from the filter work now. The only thing when the page is loaded nothing is outputted to the screen until I select a value from the dropdown.